# How to send a custom Message or transfer the assets in parity-bridges-common?

Tags: parity-bridges-common

Actually i'm working on the parity-bridges-common but i'm not able to transfer any custom message to other than the same format that they have provided.

./target/debug/substrate-relay send-message millau-to-rialto 
--source-host localhost 
--source-port $MILLAU_PORT 
--source-signer //Alice 
raw 020419ac

Can someone please guide me through this ?What is the raw 020419ac means? And how to edit it

Answer (score 1):

020419ac is the encoded version of XCM Trap instruction.
Trap(43) -> Encoded form = 020419ac

Comment: Can i send any custom message rather than the raw 020419ac?

Comment: Yes, you can.

you can get the encoded byte with the help of polakdot.js